# How to set Matlab waitbar size?

Tags: matlab

Those are basic questions, but I was unable to find a solution in matlab documentation or google.

- My waitbar have a **cancel button** and a **two lines text**, but the text wont fit inside the waitbar. I just need some autofit or to increase the waitbar height.
- Why I can't close the waitbar clicking on the "x"? The only way I can close it is typing delete(h). This happens only after I've added the Cancel button.

Waitbar creation:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','CreateCancelBtn',...
    'setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1)',...
    'Position',[100 100 200 200]); % Position' does not work
```

inside the loop:

```
    str = sprintf('Noise: %.2f (%d/%d). Planes: %.2f (%d/%d).\nOveral: %.1f%%',...
    noiseAmp,noiseId,noiseCount,slice,sliceId,sliceCount,100*perc);
    waitbar(perc,h, str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to delete the `waitbar` using the cancel button because you set a `CreateCancelBtn` callback that overrides the typical behavior and inside of your callback you *don't* delete it so it stays.

You could update your callback to set the application data *and* delete it.

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...','CreateCancelBtn',...
              'setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1); delete(gcbf);')
```

As far as changing the position, it doesn't seem to work in your constructor, but you can change it after the creation of the `waitbar`.

```
set(h, 'Position', [100 100 200 200])
```

Note that this *does not* change the position of all of the *contents* of the `waitbar`. This is because MATLAB opted to assume that the size of the `waitbar` will never change so they used `Pixel` units to define the position of all components.

There is a little trick to make this work though. You want to first (before resizing) change the `Units` of all of the components of the `waitbar` to `Normalized`. Then when you resize it, all of the components will be moved appropriately.

```
h = waitbar(0, 'Please Wait', 'CreateCancelBtn', 'disp(h)');
set(findall(h), 'Units', 'Normalized')
set(h, 'Units', 'Pixels', 'Position', [100 100 200 200])
```

Comment: Thanks! The position works as you said. About the closing, I'm unable to close the waitbar even after I stop the execution of my code. Is there a way the "X" can close the window and also do the cancel button work? Or "X" do just delete(h). It is ridiculous that I can't close the window clicking on X.

Comment: @Pedro77 What version of MATLAB are you on? It works fine for me on 2015b

Comment: I'm using 2016. Yes, the close also cancel. Sorry. But if I get an error or click cancel and don't close the waitbar, I'll not be able to close it by clicking on X and I need to type delete(h).

Comment: @Pedro77 Does the error come from your callback or the code that updates the waitbar?

Comment: My stuff error... Just imagine that the waitbar was opened and you ctrl+c at the command line. After that, the only way to close it is entering at the cmd delete(h). It is ridiculous.

Comment: @Pedro77 Interesting. I don't have 2016 so I can't check it. You could maybe try setting the `CloseRequestFcn` of the `waitbar` to `'delete(gcbf)'`